# ocserv VPN with 2 NIC CentOS6 routes

Tags: vpn, routing, centos6

I have a working installation of ocserv 0.12.6 on an old CentOS 6 machine with 2 physical interfaces: eth0 (`192.168.10.155`) and eth1 (`192.168.0.190`).
eth0 has a manual configuration and uses default gateway 192.168.10.255, eth1 also has a manual config, but no gateway specified. External ip is pointing to eth0 (ocserv port forwarded to this interface/ip).

ocserv is listening on eth0, users connect via ldap, get internet connection, it's fine.
But now there's a need to expose 192.168.0.0 network to the vpn clients.

I've tried adding route section to the config:

```
route = 192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0
route = 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

and some attempts with route = default (to pass all server's routes to clients) and those route combinations, but had no luck.

`ipv4.ip_forward` is surely enabled.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding masquerading to the second network did the job:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.55.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```